# Criticize my Sudoku solver for improvements (C# beginner)

Tags: c#, beginner, sudoku

I recently started programming and chose C# as my first language. After a couple of weeks/month now I tried to make my own Sudoku solver in a console application. I'm happy with the result, and tried to clean up my code.

But I'm not sure what I can do better at this point. I was uncertain if I created too many functions? Some of them I actually only call once (like `ValidateNumber()`, `ValidateSquare()` & `ValidateDimension()`), simply because I thought the code look cleaner.

Any suggestions for improvements or if something is bad practice?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] puzzle = {{0,0,0,8,0,0,4,2,0},
                     {5,0,0,6,7,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,5},
                     {7,4,0,1,0,0,0,4,0},
                     {0,0,9,0,3,0,7,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,4,8},
                     {8,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,9,8,0,0,3},
                     {0,9,5,0,0,3,0,0,0}};

    PrintSudoku(puzzle);

    Console.WriteLine("Press 'enter' to solve.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Solving... This may take a second. \n");
    
    SolveSudoku(puzzle);
        
}

private static void SolveSudoku(int[,] puzzle)
{
    //Copy input sudoku to a new solution array
    int[,] solution = new int[9, 9];
    Array.Copy(puzzle, 0, solution, 0, puzzle.Length);

    //Loop through each cell in the sudoku
    for (int column = 0; column < 9; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 9;)
        {
            if (puzzle[column, row] == 0) //If original cell != 0, It's already a difined number and should not be changed.
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    //Increment cell with 1
                    solution[column, row]++;

                    //If cell = 10, all tested numbers failed, reset to 0 and go back to previous cell which originally had a 0 value
                    if (solution[column, row] == 10)
                    {
                        solution[column, row] = 0;

                        do
                        {
                            if (row == 0)
                            {
                                row += 8;
                                column -= 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row -= 1;
                            }
                        } while (puzzle[column, row] != 0);

                        break;
                    }
                    //Else if number does not collide with any other row/column/square, continue with next cell
                    else if (ValidateNumber(solution, column, row))
                    {
                        row++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else //If cell != 10 and number validation failed, continue with the next number.
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            // original cell != 0, continue with next cell.
            else
            {
                row++;
            }

        }

    }

    PrintSudoku(solution);
    Console.ReadLine();

}

private static bool ValidateNumber(int[,] arr, int row, int column)
{
    //Validate that both 3x3 square and dimension(row/column) have no other cell with the same value as current array number
    if (ValidateSquare(arr, row, column) && ValidateDimension(arr, row, column))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

private static bool ValidateDimension(int[,] arr, int row, int column)
{
    //Check if the current cell match any other cell in the same row, if so return false
    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
    {
        if (column == a) //don't compare the cell with itself
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (arr[row, column] == arr[row, a])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Check if the current cell match any other cell in the same column, if so return false
    for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
    {
        if (row == b)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (arr[row, column] == arr[b, column]) //don't compare the cell with itself
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //if no other cell with same value, return true
    return true;

}

private static bool ValidateSquare(int[,] arr, int row, int column)
{
    //Compare that the current cells 3x3 grid doesn't contain the same number as current cell. 
    int rowSquare = CurrentSquare(row);
    int columnSquare = CurrentSquare(column);

    for (int i = rowSquare; i < rowSquare + 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = columnSquare; j < columnSquare + 3; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i, j] == arr[row, column])
            {
                if (i == row && j == column) //don't compare the cell with itself
                {
                    continue;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static int CurrentSquare(int coordinate)
{
    //Give the coordinate of input dimension (row/column/depth), and defines which 3x3 square of the puzzle it belongs to in the 9x9 grid. 
    int square = 0;
    switch (coordinate)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            square = 0; //Square1 in grid, Square1 start at index 0
            break;

        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            square = 3; //Square2 in grid, Square2 start at index 3
            break;

        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            square = 6; //Square3 in grid, Square3 start at index 6
            break;
    }
    return square;
}

private static void PrintSudoku(int[,] sudoku)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (j % 3 == 0 && j != 0)
            {
                Console.Write("| ");
            }
            Console.Write(sudoku[i, j] + " ");
        }

        if (i % 3 == 2 && i != 8)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("------+-------+------");                
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider storing your puzzle in a single array (size 81), which will make it easier to loop through the all values. Determining the row index is simply cell index / 9 and the column is cell index % 9, finding which square is similarly simple.

Comment: Seems like an attempt at brute-forcing the result (check all the possible solutions and discard those), but it seems that it can only backtrack one step back. If you cannot find a valid number for the current cell, you go to the previous one and change it again. But what if a change two steps removed makes all the available solutions invalid? Do you have proof that this approach will work?

Comment: @SteveFord That's a nice idea! I tried the concept out now and it simplified `SolveSudoku()` quite a lot. Just need to adjust the `ValidateNumber()` methods.

Comment: @SJuan76 It only backtrack one step back at a time. But the logic that backtrack is if a cell reach number 10, it reset to 0 and go to previous cell. Then increment that cell with 1. If that cell were to reach 10 as well, it will go back an additional cell. So it will try every possible combination out. Though.. as Zachary Vance pointed out, if an invalid sudoku puzzle is inserted the code will fail. So I will need to fix that too.

Comment: To complete the review you may accept the most useful answer with a green mark.

Comment: This medium.com/@eneko/… shows an approach to solving hard Sudokus using a number of techniques that works well, unfortunately it is written in Swift but the approach is well documented describing the logic. It uses a slightly different approach of starting with all possible values in every cell then removes them until only one is left in each cell. It describes several advanced ideas, look at identical Sibling Solvers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a beginner this is actually quite good.

For future reference, we can provide better reviews when the entire program is included. This code does not include the `Using` statements nor does it provide the class declaration.

You might also want to consider some of the heuristics of Sudoku, such as solve for the number that appears the most in the puzzle first.

## Functions

As @Ouch42 indicated, functions are not just about reusable code.

Good programming is the art or science of breaking problems down into smaller problems until they are very easy to solve. They make maintaining code (adding features, fixing bugs) easier. Quite possibly you could use one or two more functions because the function `SolveSudoku(int[,] puzzle)` is too complex which means it does too much. The first thing I would do is move the last 2 lines of the function into `Main()`.

```
        PrintSudoku(solution);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

These 2 lines are not part of solving the Sudoku puzzle. This would mean returning the solution matrix rather than returning void.

Other considerations about the number of functions to create:

- Readability: Is each function easy to read and understand.
- Length of the function: a function should be no more than a single screen in your IDE or editor.
- The depth of indentation: if you find yourself indenting more than 3 times you may want to add a function. This can improve readability and comprehension.

## The Single Responsibility Principle

There is a programming principle called the Single Responsibility Principle that applies here. The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) states:

> that every module, class, or function should have responsibility over a single part of the functionality provided by the software, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by that module, class or function.

As your programs get more complex you will want to learn about object oriented programming and some core principles of object oriented programming which is called [SOLID programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). The Single Responsibility Principle is the First pillar of SOLID programming.

## Next Steps

Read the puzzle from a file so that the program is more generic and can be reused.

Comment: Great feedback! I will adjust to return the solution and keep each function to its dedicated purpose. I think it make more sense as well after hearing you and Ouch42 out. Will also try to simplify `SolveSudoku(int[,] puzzle)`. I agree, that part is a bit complex to read even for me. Not the best sign when I'm the one who wrote it. Maybe I can split it into more defined functions.

I will read up on SOLID programming as well! Then attempt your next steps suggestion.
Thank you for taking time reviewing this :)

Answer (score 5):

Overall, your solver is reasonable. All your functions look well-defined and they should exist. The worst-looking function is `SolveSudoku`, so that's the one I'll talk about some improvements for. It's OK (very explicit and self-contained, which is nice), but it could be much more readable.

FYI The logic you're using is called "backtracking" -- fill in something that looks good, and if it fails, "back track" to the last choice you made and try making a different one. It's a very common pattern for solvers. Ultimately, your program will be slower if you only use backtracking, because you'll re-do a lot of the work over and over when you backtrack.

The only functionality I'd add (aside from reading the sudoku from a file as suggested by another reviewer) is to deal with sudokus that don't have a valid solution. Just print "no solution" or something. Right now your backtracking logic will blow up and try to access a negative column.

### Remove Nesting

Things can be hard to read with this level of nesting. On the one hand, all the logic is in one place. On the other hand, it's hard to understand. I'll talk about some specific ways to take out layers below.

### Separate cell traversal

Consider whether to add a `NextCell` and `PrevCell` helper function which takes in a row/col, and returns a row/col. This does remove a little nesting, but more importantly, it makes the intent clearer. Right now you have a lot of scattered Row++ and break lines, and it's hard for the reader. The downside is that it splits up the logic a bit.

#### Switch to single-dimensional coordinates

- One suggestion (which goes well with your iteration/backtracking method) might be to keep track of the current cell as a number 0-80 (or 1-81). That would remove a level of nesting, and it would also make the backtracking logic easier.
- Alternatively, you could initialize an array of all non-zero coordinates at the start, and use an index into this array. This makes going forward and back VERY easy--you always increment/decrement the index by exactly one. You can optionally use a 3D coordinate (row, column, square) which might be easier in some ways. Make sure to check how the run time changes. And array also allows you to try filling in squares in various orders to see if one order works better.

#### Use "continue" and "return"

One common trick to remove nesting is to replace:

```
if (puzzle[column, row] == 0) { //If original cell != 0, It's already a difined number and should not be changed.
  ...main logic...
} else {
  row++;
}
```

with

```
if (puzzle[column, row] != 0) { //If original cell != 0, It's already a difined number and should not be changed.
  row++;
  continue;
}
...main logic...
```

This has the downside of being less explicit (the reader has to think about logic more), but removing nesting does help readers a lot.

### Separate out the backtracking logic.

`SolveSudoku`'s basic logic is to, in a loop:

- Look at the current cell
- Try filling in each number, skipping impossible ones
- If this is possible, we're done. Go to the next cell, skipping clues (pre-filled-in cells)
- If this is impossible, we're done. Backtrack to the last cell, skipping clues

However, the actual logic is filled with continue, break, and increments/decrements to row. It would be better if each case visually looked the same. There are a few options.

One option is to pull out a helper, which I call `GuessCell` in the pseudocode below:

```
private static bool GuessCell(int[,] puzzle, int row, int col) {
  // returns True if we should go to the next cell, and False if we should backtrack to the previous cell.
  // Modifies puzzle in place like now.
}
private static void SolveSudoku(int[,] puzzle, int row, int col) {
  while (int row=0, int col=0; col <=9 && row <=9; ) {
    if (GuessCell(row, col)) {
       // go to next free cell
    } else {
       // go to previous free cell
    }
  }
  // Solved!
}
```

Another common option for backtracking solvers is to solve the problem recursively, but this looks radically different. It's basically no longer a change at this point, it's a rewrite, but I think it's interesting to share this approach too.

```
private static Nullable<int[,]> SolveSudoku(int[,] puzzle) {
  int[,] solution = new int[9, 9];
  return SolveSudokuFromCell(puzzle, solution, 0, 0);
}
private static Nullable<int[,]> SolveSudokuFromCell(int[,] puzzle, int[,] solution, int row, int col) {
  int nextRow = row + 1, nextCol = col;
  if (nextRow == 10) {
    nextRow=0; nextCol++;
  }
  if (nextCol == 10) return solution; // Done!

  if (puzzle[row][col] != 0) {
    solution[row][col] = puzzle[row][col];
    return SolveSudokuFromCell(puzzle, solution, nextRow, nextCol);
  }
  for (int number=1; number<=9; number++) {
    puzzle[row][col] = number;
    if (ValidateNumber(solution, column, row)) {
      // Try filling in the rest of the cells
      Nullable<int[,]> res = SolveSudokuFromCell(puzzle, nextRow, nextCol);
      if (res != null) return res;
    }
    // If that number didn't work, try the next
  }
  return null; // If no number work, backtrack
}
```

P.S. I wrote this last one to demonstrate the logic, but [please treat it as pseudocode. I don't know C# and haven't tried running it, sorry! (`Nullable<int[,]>` probably isn't a real thing?)

Comment: Yeah, `Nullable<T>` is specifically for value types ;) `int[,]` is a reference type and so will accept `null` already, though with [nullable reference types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) enabled you would indicate that it is expected to be null by writing `int[,]?` (and the `?` suffix also works on value types to create a `Nullable<T>`, so you don't see the latter much)

Comment: For a beginning programmer who is teaching themselves, recursion may be a bit much. I would use recursion to solve the problem myself. Good review.

Comment: I think a backtracking solver is a great place to learn recursion. It's how I discovered it myself (for tic-tac-toe).

Answer (score 4):

Functions are not just about reusing code. I thing the way you "cut" the code using specific functions is quite clean.

I would strongly suggest using summaries above functions to describe things, even if your function names are quite explicatives

At last, I would probably have a GetSolution() method returning a string that the main function could print, instead of a void PrintSudoku() method. I think that letting the main function responsible of all inputs/outputs is cleaner.

But I really think your code is clean.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yeah that sounds reasonable, returning the solution makes more sense now that you mention it, I will try that out. Good to know I didn't overuse functions as well!

Answer (score 1):

A possible addition to the other answers (which I fully agree with) is to design this using classes instead. C# works fine as a procedural language but really is designed with OO in mind.

I think it's easier to get into a SOLID mindset for a beginner like that. A short sketch of that:

We can start with a definition of a partially solved Sudoku "board"

```
class PartialSudoku {
 int[,] Values;
}
```

It should probably have a constructor that checks that the number of rows and columns are correct and so on to fail early.
Further we can either overload the ToString() method or add a SudokuPrinter.

```
class SudokuPrinter {
  string SudokuAsString(PartialSudoku sudoku) { ... }
}
```

Then we may have many different solvers, so we would add an interface:

```
interface SudokuSolver {
  PartialSudoku Solve(PartialSudoku sudoku)
}
```

Now each possible solver just have to implement this solver specification, and they automatically gets forced into the same structure and into a single responsibility.

Here, we also can have a discussion about the return type - what is the result of solving?

Should we have a different class `FullSudoku`?

Maybe some `SolveResult` class with a `status` that we can check?

If we use a fairly modern C#, we should perhaps enable reference nullability and call it `PartialSudoku?` instead?

Should we do the same for the printer? Maybe we want one printer to print 0 on unsolved, but another just leaving them empty? Maybe one where we draw boxes the way you did, or another with thin boxes around each digit and thick around each block, or one completely plain?

With this approach we can combine many such ideas.

The resulting main function is very similar:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] puzzle = {{0,0,0,8,0,0,4,2,0},
                     {5,0,0,6,7,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,5},
                     {7,4,0,1,0,0,0,4,0},
                     {0,0,9,0,3,0,7,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,4,8},
                     {8,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,9,8,0,0,3},
                     {0,9,5,0,0,3,0,0,0}};
    PartialSudoku sudoku = new PartialSudoku(puzzle)
    ISudokuSolver solver = GetSolver(); //maybe select between different from config
    SudokuPrinter printer = new SudokuPrinter();

    Console.WriteLine(printer.SudokuAsString(sudoku));    
    Console.WriteLine("Press 'enter' to solve.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Solving... This may take a second. \n");
    
    PartialSudoku solved = solver.Solve(sudoku);
    Console.WriteLine(printer.SudokuAsString(solved ));                
}
```

Not everybody likes this style, and it absolutely adds code, but for say, being able to switch between several solvers and adding new easily, it really shines. Personally I find it not too enterprisey.